# Display saved checkbox value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some checkbox options that I save in the DB. I was able to view and also select multiple options and save them in the DB. The issue is that I want to display the saved information but I don't know how to do that.

```
<form action="save_comp.php" method="post">
<?php
//Display 

include ('mysql_connect.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competency ");
//$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

echo"<input type='checkbox' name='comp[]' value= ".$row['id']." /> ".$row['competency']." <br />";


}

?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Save into DB

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//$id = 3;

include ('mysql_connect.php');

$insStr = ''; 
foreach($_POST['comp'] as $val){ $insStr .=$val.","; }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO competency_result (user_id,result) VALUES ( '$id', '$insStr' )") or die(mysql_error()); 

echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>'; 
?>
```

All I want to do now is to display the saved information in a table format. I tried doing this but it only showed me the saved ID

```
<?php
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competency_result WHERE user_id = '$user'")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>&nbsp;$row[result]</td>";                
?>

<?php  
    echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: first thing you need to stop using mysql which is depecated http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php and secondly you are using value= ".$row['id']." so this is what will be stored. what you add after your input will just be a string. so this may be what you need to replace. and another thing <input> is an auto close tag so you you do not need to do the />

Comment: Thanks a lot. i changed the id to the value and it saves the value in the DB. but can't i just save the id and find a way to query the DB so i can retrieve the details via the ID

Comment: you deffinitly can retrieve the data from the ID then this mean you will need to create another sql query to fetch the data in your table(s). I would recommend to do something like $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM "); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo whatever, this is the basic but you should figure out something out of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="save_comp.php" method="post">
<?php
//Display 

include ('mysql_connect.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competency ");
//$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

echo"<input type='checkbox' name='comp[". $row['id']. "]' value='". $row['competency'] ."' /> ".$row['competency']." <br />";


}

?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What i need is to display the selected values. i already have it saved in the DB, i just want to display the selected checkboxes. my code only saves the ID of the data in the checkbox. i want it to display the info not the id.

Comment: @anelka If you want to stick with IDs then you need to make 2 queries to the DB: select * from competency and select * from competency_result WHERE user_id = $user. Then you need to explode(',', $row['result']) from competency_result and select rows matching given ID from competency table. Basically you have a very bad DB design.

Comment: Thanks.. that really helped. one thing. am trying to display all the result but am only getting the first one in the array. am guessing it has something to do with my loop. could you help me take a look at it?

Comment: $separate = explode(" ", $row['result']);

for($i = 0; $i < count($separate); $i++){
 
 $quest=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competency WHERE id = '$separate[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
 
 
 
 
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($quest))
{
 echo"<tr>";
 
  echo"<td>&nbsp;$rows[competency]  <br /></td>";  
}
}

Comment: @anelka Perhaps you should replace echo"<td>&nbsp;$rows[competency] <br /></td>";  with echo"<td>&nbsp;$rows['competency'] <br /></td>";

Answer (score 0):

If you want to checkboxes check then you can try with below code:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM competency ");
    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {

    $focus=explode(",",$row['name']);
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="focus[]" value="Art" <?php if(in_array("Comp",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
    <input type="checkbox" name="focus[]" value="Mathematics" <?php if(in_array("Mathematics",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
    <input type="checkbox" name="focus[]" value="Dance" <?php if(in_array("Dance",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```